# Setter and value property doesn't work correctly

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the value of input node after set `setter`. But no result.

```js
$('#inp2')[0].value = 'initail value';
alert($('#inp2')[0].value);

//setter
Object.defineProperty($('#inp2')[0], "value", { set: function (x) { alert(x); } });
$('#inp2')[0].value = 'explicit call fires';  
alert($('#inp2')[0].value);

$('#inp2, #inp1').on('keyup', function(){
 $(this).siblings('p').html(this.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><input id="inp1">
<p>
value of input1: 
</p>
</div>

<div>
<input id="inp2">
<p>
value of input2: 
</p>
</div>
```

How can I achieve a result so that the input value changes and the `setter` is triggered when the characters are entered?

Comment: You defined a property called `value` but didn't set it.  Why were you expecting this to work?  Also, it would be nice if the code were here in the question as a runable snippet instead of in an external fiddle.

Comment: Edited.
 `Value` has already been set before. Can you explain in more detail where the error is?

Comment: If you want `.value= x` to trigger a property setter then you have to actually assign `.value = x` somewher as you did in your first two "explicit" example.  But in the keyup handler,  calling `.html(this.value)` will not invoke the setter.  Do you think it should?

Comment: Yes, it should. When the 'keyup' event is triggered, the setter should be called.
But the problem starts elsewhere. If you look at the code: `$('#inp2')[0].value = 'explicit call fires';  alert($('#inp2')[0].value);` will be "undefined". I don't understand why the setter does this.

Answer (score 0):

You are mistaken if you think that calling `.html()` on the `div` element below the `input` box will somehow trigger the `value` property setter on the `input` element.

Once you target the right element, calling `.val()` will likely do what you want.

But here are some counterexamples illustrating why what you're doing doesn't work.

```js
thing = $('#inp1')[0];

Object.defineProperty(thing, "value", { set: function (x) { alert(x); } });

thing.value = 'a'; // OK.  Calls the property directly

$(thing).value = 'b'; // nope.  $(thing) is a query.  We pollute the query object with a .value.

$(thing)[0].value = 'c'; // OK.  We just got the element back and called the setter directly.

$(thing).html('d'); // .html() doesn't call `value` property setter.  Sorry!

try {
$(thing)[0].html('e'); // EXCEPTION: this will throw.  html is not defined on the element, it's jquery,
} catch(ignore) { console.error(ignore) }

$(thing).val('f'); // OK: .val DOES call value property setter

try {
$(thing)[0].val('g'); // EXCEPTION: this will throw.  val is not defined on the element, it's jquery, 
} catch(ignore) { console.error(ignore) }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div><input id="inp1">
```

Furthermore, you're defining a property setter on the `input` element with id `inp2`, but you're replacing the html of the `div` element below that.  Even if you targetted the right element, replacing its html with `.html()` wouldn't fire the `value` setter.  For that you would need to call `.val()`